# avoid duplicate key names by adding suffix

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I need to have my title as the keyname the problem is this could cause problems with duplicate keynames, how can i check if it exists and add -1 to the end if it does, or add -2 to the end if -1 exists.

```
keyName = "hello"
duplicates = Entry.get_by_key_name(keyName)
            if duplicates:
                keyName = keyName+("-1")
```

How do i loop through adding 1 until I find a unique name?

any help is much appreciated
J

Comment: Why do you want to do this? The point of a key name is to give you a unique natural key; if you append a suffix, you no longer know what the key is, so you may as well use an autogenerated ID instead of a key name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
keyName = "hello"

testName = keyName
suffix = 0
while Entry.get_by_key_name(testName):
  suffix += 1
  testName = "%s-%d" % (keyName, suffix)

keyName = testName
```

Answer (score 2):

A different way to think about the problem:

```
from itertools import imap, dropwhile, count

def make_name(i):
    stem = "foo"
    return stem if i == 0 else "{0}-{1}".format(stem, i)

def in_universe(name):
    return bool(Entry.get_by_key_name(name))

seq = dropwhile(in_universe, imap(make_name, count()))
keyName = seq.next()
```

Comment: Except the first attempt should have no suffix.